# Get the value of a combo box with text block

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a combo box of patterns for a snake's color and I want to know which pattern the user chose,I added pictures to show the available patterns,but when I do
pattern=combobox2.Text; It doesn't show me the text i'm looking for.

```
<ComboBox Name="ComboBox2" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15" Canvas.Left="320" Canvas.Top="222" Width="135" Height="24">
        <ComboBoxItem  
         Name="Pattern1" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="Pics/snakepattern.jpg" Height="12" Width="19"></Image>
                <TextBlock Text=" Pattern1"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem
        Name="Pattern2" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="Pics/snakepattern2.jpg" Height="14" Width="20"></Image>
                <TextBlock Text=" Pattern2"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem  
        Name="Pattern3" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="15">
                <Image Source="Pics/snakepattern3.jpg" Height="20"></Image>
                <TextBlock Text=" Pattern3"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem 
        Name="Pattern4" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="Pics/snakepattern4.jpg" Height="13" Width="20"></Image>
                <TextBlock Text=" Pattern4"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem 
        Name="Pattern5" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="Pics/snakepattern5.png" Height="17" Width="23"></Image>
                <TextBlock Text=" Pattern5"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

I want it to show me the texts "Pattern1","Pattern2" (according to what the user chose)
how do I do that in the c# code?

Comment: You should use SelectedItem instead of Text

Comment: Iv'e tried doind it like that :ComboBoxItem cbi = 
                  (ComboBoxItem)ComboBox2.SelectedItem;
                    string pattern = cbi.Content.ToString();
                    MessageBox.Show(pattern);                                                                but the message box shows me  : System.Windows.Controls.Stackpanel     so I think I need to access it somehow through the stack panel inside the combobox but I don't know how

Comment: Content is a StackPanel of course. Do `var stackPanel = (StackPanel)cbi.Content;` Then get the second child like `var textBlock = (TextBlock)stackPanel.Children[1];` Finally get the text by `textBlock.Text`.

Comment: It worked thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a view model like this:

```
public class SnakePattern
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ImageSource Image { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<SnakePattern> Patterns { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<SnakePattern>();

    private SnakePattern selectedPattern;
    public SnakePattern SelectedPattern
    {
        get { return selectedPattern; }
        set
        {
            selectedPattern = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedPattern)));
        }
    }
}
```

and bind the ComboBox to it like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Patterns}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPattern}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Height="12" Width="19"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Initialize it in the constructor of your MainWindow, and assign it to the MainWindow `DataContext` property like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var vm = new ViewModel();
    vm.Patterns.Add(new SnakePattern
    {
        Name = "Pattern 1",
        Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Pics/snakepattern1.jpg"))
    });
    ...
    vm.SelectedPattern = vm.Patterns[0];

    DataContext = vm;
}
```

To get the selected pattern, just access the DataContext (or keep the view model in a member variable):

```
var vm = (ViewModel)DataContext;
var selectedPattern = vm.SelectedPattern;
```

Comment: It looks really complicated..to get the values of the snake's color i simply wrote color=combobox1.Text; I only want either the text in the textblock or the name of the combobox item-that's why they are the same here,I already know how to change the snake's pattern I only need to know which pattern is chosen-pattern 1 or 2 etc..

Comment: Complicated for the moment, perhaps. But you'll find this pattern (called  model/view/view model, MVVM) in any serious WPF application. The earlier you adopt it, the better. It will make many things easier, especially when you have a lot af data bindings. For example you may now bind a snake's pattern directly to the same view model, e.g. with an ImageBrush in XAML, like `<ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding SelectedPattern.Image}"/>`

Comment: Yeah but the thing is i'm doing this for a school work for tomorrow so i'm trying to keep it simple and easy that's the last thing I need to add before it's done and I have limited time today,i'm also a beginner so complicated things are tough for me to understand.Do you know perhaps a quick solution for this that will give me the chosen box's content?

Comment: I did it from this website : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/wpf-combobox/   They do show how to find current item but do I have to put it in an array for that?